# Passing parameters to npm ci

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, npm-install, ng-build

Since the introduction of `npm ci` some time ago, this is the recommended way for building applications - especially for CI environments and so on.

I have now the case where I am interested in specifying additional options (e.g. the base href) when making the prod build of my Angular (9) application. The command would be:

`ng build --prod --baseHref=/frontend/`

What would be the counterpart when using `npm ci`?

I have tried:

`npm ci --only=production --baseHref=/frontend/`

but it seems that the additional parameters are not passed through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm ci` only installs modules and does not invoke `npm build`

> This command is similar to `npm-install`

for more information about the difference between `npm i` (`npm install`) and `npm ci`, refer to [npm-ci documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html#description)

this means that there is no connection to `npm build` and will not execute something like `ng build --prod --baseHref=/frontend/`

Comment: Thank you, this means that I'll still need to trigger the ng build in addition and I save time "only" during modules installation